# CORS/CORB for stats.nba.com

Tags: javascript, api, cors, cross-origin-read-blocking

I had someone ask about APIs and specifically wanted to create an example using the NBA API (stats.nba.com).  Admittedly I'm not an an expert but I thought I'd work out an example using fetch.

I've found some documentation on the API endpoints ([link](https://github.com/seemethere/nba_py/wiki/stats.nba.com-Endpoint-Documentation)) and can compose a URI which resolves to the JSON data when accessed directly from the address bar.

The issue I'm getting is that when I tried this using fetch the API doesn't seem to allow for CORS so I did some reading and it's my understanding I should be able to make an opaque request using 'no-cors'.  However, when I use the 'no-cors' parameter I get a CORB (cross origin blocking) error which I can't find much documentation on but if the name is an indication then I would think no cross origin requests could be made.

The part that makes that assumption confusing is that while I can't seem to find any examples using the NBA API client-side I can see a number of libraries that would appear to use the same endpoints I've tested using Python and other server-side approaches.  In fact the documentation above comes from a git that does just that.

As an alternative, I did try another example using the NHL API (statsapi.web.nhl.com) and it seems to work fine and I can produce a team roster list.

Here is a simplified piece of code that demonstrates the issue.  'dataURL1' works fine with 'cors' but dataURL2 gives errors both with 'cors' and 'no-cors'.

```js
function test01() {            
  var dataURL1 = "http://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/8";
  var dataURL2 = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster/?Season=2017-18&TeamID=1610612737";                                 
  
  /*
  - if dataURL1 is used there is no issue with 'cors' parameter
  - if dataURL2 is used with 'cors' parameter, 
    a no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' message is given
  - if dataURL2 is used with 'no-cors' parameter, 
    a CORB message is given
  */      
  fetch(dataURL2, { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log("data retrieved");                    
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Mostly I need to confirm that I'm not missing something and that I can't make the request via the client.  If this is the case I would appreciate some direction to an article or content that explains why the request can be made server-side but not client-side.

Answer (score 3):

The NHL URL works because its server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (plus other CORS headers) whereas the NBA server does not. Since you do not control the servers in question, you can't change this behavior. You could have a server you *do* control perform the fetch and have that server of yours respond with the contents in a CORS-friendly way when the browser sends a request.

The same-origin policy is a mechanism by which the browser prevents scripts from reading resources that exist on different origins from the requesting script. If you preform an HTTP request with software that is not a browser, CORS won't apply, since CORS is a security measure native to Web browsers.

`no-cors` is a way to say, "Yes, I *know* this is a cross-origin resource. Fetch it anyway, but of course don't let me read the response." This is an "opaque response" and can be used when it is possible to render the contents directly to the user (e.g., a cross-origin image placed into an `<img>` tag) while keeping the contents inaccessible to scripts who try to learn about its contents.

However, JSON data is not a kind of data for which this opaque-response functionality makes sense. CORB is when the browser decides, "There is no way for this response to useful to the requesting page; I'm worried this is being done purely to exploit a security vulnerability. Therefore, I will not even, e.g., parse this JSON."

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense as to why it isn't resolved client-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the headers that are returned from http://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/8 you'll see Access-Control-Allow-Origin

This header allows the browser from a different domain than nhl.com make a request to the api.

If you look at the headers from https://stats.nba.com/stats/commonteamroster/?Season=2017-18&TeamID=1610612737 you will not see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

The nba.com service isn't setup to be called cross domain from the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin